# How to read the home key on an iOS keyboard using IOHIDManager or Bluetooth?

Tags: macos, bluetooth, keyboard, hid, iokit

I am attempting to use the home key on an iOS keyboard for the purpose of an `Esc` key. I am able to use `IOHIDManager` to read the keys on the keyboard with the exception of the iOS home key.

My understanding is that passing `NULL` to `IOHIDManagerSetDeviceMatching` should match all the types in [IOHIDUsageTables](https://opensource.apple.com/source/IOHIDFamily/IOHIDFamily-247/IOHIDFamily/IOHIDUsageTables.h) as below:

```
// clang -framework coreFoundation -framework IOKit ./HID.c -o hid
// sudo ./hid

#include <IOKit/hid/IOHIDManager.h>
#include <IOKit/hid/IOHIDValue.h>

void myHIDKeyboardCallback(void* context, IOReturn result, void* sender, IOHIDValueRef value)
{
    IOHIDElementRef elem = IOHIDValueGetElement(value);
    uint32_t scancode = IOHIDElementGetUsage(elem);
    long pressed = IOHIDValueGetIntegerValue(value);
    printf("scancode: %d, pressed: %ld\n", scancode, pressed);
}

int main(void)
{
    IOHIDManagerRef hidManager = IOHIDManagerCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kIOHIDOptionsTypeNone);
    IOHIDManagerSetDeviceMatching(hidManager, NULL);
    IOHIDManagerRegisterInputValueCallback(hidManager, myHIDKeyboardCallback, NULL);
    IOHIDManagerScheduleWithRunLoop(hidManager, CFRunLoopGetMain(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
    IOHIDManagerOpen(hidManager, kIOHIDOptionsTypeNone);
    CFRunLoopRun();
}
```

Using `PacketLogger.app` (from Apple's `Hardware IO Tools`) I am able to log the following where the first key press is the home key followed by a press of the tilde key.

```
[Jan 16 18:31:06.631]  [HII receive]  HID Interrupt: [A1] Unknown [03] Event Data [ 01 00 00 ]
[Jan 16 18:31:06.730]  [HII receive]  HID Interrupt: [A1] Unknown [03] Event Data [ 00 00 00 ]
[Jan 16 18:31:07.805]  [HII receive]  HID Interrupt: [A1] Keyboard [01] Event Data [ 00 00 35 00 00 00 00 00 ]
[Jan 16 18:31:07.905]  [HII receive]  HID Interrupt: [A1] Keyboard [01] Event Data [ 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ]
```

Perhaps it is because of the `Unknown` event that it is not available via `IOHIDManager`.

Creating a kernel extension and reading directly from Bluetooth could also be an option, here is the expanded logging from above:

```
[Jan 16 18:31:06.631]  [HII receive]  HID Interrupt: [A1] Unknown [03] Event Data [ 01 00 00 ]
               HID Interrupt: [A1] Unknown [03] Event Data [ 01 00 00 ]
[Jan 16 18:31:06.631]  [L2CAP RECEIVE]  Channel ID: 0x0041  Length: 0x0005 (05) [ A1 03 01 00 00 ]
               Channel ID: 0x0041  Length: 0x0005 (05) [ A1 03 01 00 00 ]
               00000000: 0500 4100 a103 0100 00                   ..A......
[Jan 16 18:31:06.631]  [ACL RECEIVE]  Data [Handle: 0x000B, Packet Boundary Flags: 0x2, Length: 0x0009 (9)]
               Data [Handle: 0x000B, Packet Boundary Flags: 0x2, Length: 0x0009 (9)]
               Packet Boundary Flags: [10] 0x02 - First packet of Higher Layer Message (i.e. start of an L2CAP packet)
               Broadcast Flags: [00] 0x00 - Point-to-point
               Data (0x0009 bytes)
[Jan 16 18:31:06.631]  [ACL RECEIVE]  00000000: 0b20 0900 0500 4100 a103 0100 00         . ....A......
               00000000: 0b20 0900 0500 4100 a103 0100 00         . ....A......
[Jan 16 18:31:06.730]  [HII receive]  HID Interrupt: [A1] Unknown [03] Event Data [ 00 00 00 ]
               HID Interrupt: [A1] Unknown [03] Event Data [ 00 00 00 ]
[Jan 16 18:31:06.730]  [L2CAP RECEIVE]  Channel ID: 0x0041  Length: 0x0005 (05) [ A1 03 00 00 00 ]
               Channel ID: 0x0041  Length: 0x0005 (05) [ A1 03 00 00 00 ]
               00000000: 0500 4100 a103 0000 00                   ..A......
[Jan 16 18:31:06.730]  [ACL RECEIVE]  Data [Handle: 0x000B, Packet Boundary Flags: 0x2, Length: 0x0009 (9)]
               Data [Handle: 0x000B, Packet Boundary Flags: 0x2, Length: 0x0009 (9)]
               Packet Boundary Flags: [10] 0x02 - First packet of Higher Layer Message (i.e. start of an L2CAP packet)
               Broadcast Flags: [00] 0x00 - Point-to-point
               Data (0x0009 bytes)
[Jan 16 18:31:06.730]  [ACL RECEIVE]  00000000: 0b20 0900 0500 4100 a103 0000 00         . ....A......
               00000000: 0b20 0900 0500 4100 a103 0000 00         . ....A......
[Jan 16 18:31:07.805]  [HII receive]  HID Interrupt: [A1] Keyboard [01] Event Data [ 00 00 35 00 00 00 00 00 ]
               HID Interrupt: [A1] Keyboard [01] Event Data [ 00 00 35 00 00 00 00 00 ]
               Modifier keys 00
                        NUM_LOCK    [FALSE]
                        CAPS_LOCK   [FALSE]
                        SCROLL_LOCK [FALSE]
                        COMPOSE     [FALSE]
                        KANA        [FALSE]
               Reserved      00
               Keycode 1 35 Keycode 2 00 Keycode 3 00 Keycode 4 00 Keycode 5 00 Keycode 6 00 
[Jan 16 18:31:07.805]  [L2CAP RECEIVE]  Channel ID: 0x0041  Length: 0x000A (10) [ A1 01 00 00 35 00 00 00 00 00 ]
               Channel ID: 0x0041  Length: 0x000A (10) [ A1 01 00 00 35 00 00 00 00 00 ]
               00000000: 0a00 4100 a101 0000 3500 0000 0000       ..A.....5.....
[Jan 16 18:31:07.805]  [ACL RECEIVE]  Data [Handle: 0x000B, Packet Boundary Flags: 0x2, Length: 0x000E (14)]
               Data [Handle: 0x000B, Packet Boundary Flags: 0x2, Length: 0x000E (14)]
               Packet Boundary Flags: [10] 0x02 - First packet of Higher Layer Message (i.e. start of an L2CAP packet)
               Broadcast Flags: [00] 0x00 - Point-to-point
               Data (0x000e bytes)
[Jan 16 18:31:07.805]  [ACL RECEIVE]  00000000: 0b20 0e00 0a00 4100 a101 0000 3500 0000  . ....A.....5...
               00000000: 0b20 0e00 0a00 4100 a101 0000 3500 0000  . ....A.....5...
               00000010: 0000                                     ..
[Jan 16 18:31:07.905]  [HII receive]  HID Interrupt: [A1] Keyboard [01] Event Data [ 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ]
               HID Interrupt: [A1] Keyboard [01] Event Data [ 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ]
               Modifier keys 00
                        NUM_LOCK    [FALSE]
                        CAPS_LOCK   [FALSE]
                        SCROLL_LOCK [FALSE]
                        COMPOSE     [FALSE]
                        KANA        [FALSE]
               Reserved      00
               Keycode 1 00 Keycode 2 00 Keycode 3 00 Keycode 4 00 Keycode 5 00 Keycode 6 00 
[Jan 16 18:31:07.905]  [L2CAP RECEIVE]  Channel ID: 0x0041  Length: 0x000A (10) [ A1 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ]
               Channel ID: 0x0041  Length: 0x000A (10) [ A1 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ]
               00000000: 0a00 4100 a101 0000 0000 0000 0000       ..A...........
[Jan 16 18:31:07.905]  [ACL RECEIVE]  Data [Handle: 0x000B, Packet Boundary Flags: 0x2, Length: 0x000E (14)]
               Data [Handle: 0x000B, Packet Boundary Flags: 0x2, Length: 0x000E (14)]
               Packet Boundary Flags: [10] 0x02 - First packet of Higher Layer Message (i.e. start of an L2CAP packet)
               Broadcast Flags: [00] 0x00 - Point-to-point
               Data (0x000e bytes)
[Jan 16 18:31:07.905]  [ACL RECEIVE]  00000000: 0b20 0e00 0a00 4100 a101 0000 0000 0000  . ....A.........
               00000000: 0b20 0e00 0a00 4100 a101 0000 0000 0000  . ....A.........
               00000010: 0000                                     ..
```

Comment: Using `IOHIDManager`, have you tried using [IOHIDManagerRegisterInputReportCallback](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iokit/1438397-iohidmanagerregisterinputreportc?language=objc) and decoding the report yourself? I'm wondering if `IOHIDManagerRegisterInputValueCallback` doesn't support decoding values in "unknown" tables. I don't have one of these keyboards handy unfortunately, so I can't test it myself.

Comment: Unfortunately the callback is not triggered using `IOHIDManagerRegisterInputReportCallback` either.

Comment: I discovered the original code does work, but it doesn't work 99% of the time. I was able to determine that the key is `kHIDUsage_Csmr_ACHome`.

Running `sudo packetlogger | grep 'A1.*03.*01 00 00'` works every time though.

Comment: Weird, I guess it'd come down to tracing the event through the relevant bits of the kernel in order to figure out what's going on and where exactly the events are being dropped.

Comment: If I disconnect the keyboard and press the home key to reconnect, there is one kHIDUsage_Csmr_ACHome event sent but then it looks like Bluetooth seizes control. Previously when I was able to get consistent readings I was also running multiple instances of `packetlogger`, so perhaps that disrupted the Bluetooth control.

Comment: Given this is Apple hardware *and* software, this question is perhaps something Apple DTS can help with?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) was seizing control of the input and discarding the home key, which ironically I had installed in attempt to remap the home key to escape. Uninstalling it resolved the issue.